# NodeJS socket.io get user from db not from socket emit

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Okay so I have a little problem at the moment. The problem is that I have this socket.emit:

```
socket.emit("item-bought-intel", {
                username: "Dievas", // <<<< problem
                itemId: "5bb134bfc94e3d0dd45b0957",
                item_title: "Ivory",
                item_price: 75,
                item_power: 5
            })
```

And I can run this code through console and then buy item if user has enough gold. But point is that I can find any user in website and see his gold and then use his username in this socket.emit to emit it through console and buy items to his account. This happens because on server side I find user by `username` from socket.emit and check if he has enough gold to buy specified item. Currently this is my code on server side:

```
     User.findOne({username: data.username}).then((user) => {});
```

I need to know is there any way how could I found user in DB without using `username` in socket.emit ?

Maybe I should use user ID in socket.emit ? Because in website I do not display ID's of users anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do not show the ID, it is still available if you look for it in the browser, so you would end up in the same problem as now.

If you don't want to create a user login system, i recommend looking into [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/), which allows you send the a package from the browser to your server and be quite certain that no one has tampered with it.

This way you can even continue using the username for database lookup, without huge security issues.

This is all assuming that you are not working on something very important. If that is the case, you might want to look into more secure methods.

Comment: Theres simple login/register system then user is stored to session. But I believe I cannot use `req.session.userId` in the socket?